# How to add addition column setting property for a Single line of textbox or any predefiend sharepoint column type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

[image]

How to add additional custom properties for the column under Additional Column Property as shown above on pic for predefined type such as Single line text or multiple lines of text etc. so that I can programmatically generate(dynamically) the form(NewForm, EditForm & DisplayForm) by reading these values from code.
Example :-

Some additional configurations are appended as below:

- **Availability for user**: If users choose:
- **Hidden**: This column will not be seen by non-Admin users. It can only
  be seen by Admin users.
- **Editable**: This column will be available and editable for all users.
- **Read-only**: This column will be visible but read-only for non-Admin users. It can only be editable for Admin users.
- **Information Group**: This column is belonging to the selected
  Information Group which is a master data list. For each information
  group, the system will display the configured column accordingly
  within the selected group.

Please help me to find out the way to add these additional properties to all the predefined column type.

Note :- I know how to add Custom properties for new Custom type but I need to know/is it possible to add these custom types for the existing SharePoint fields type.

Comment: This sounds like a Bad Idea. What are you ultimately trying to do? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I second my predecessor's comment. You're starting your question with the "How". Give us the "What" and we'll tell you the "How"...

Comment: @Thriggle please take a look on the question again

Comment: Thanks, Sourav. I don't believe you'll be able to add those properties to existing column types and achieve the functionality you're looking for. I think the better option to explore (based on your requirements) is a custom form. The business logic (such as deciding whether to display and/or be editable based on audience) would be implemented on the form, rather than inherent to the underlying columns.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment, as part of my development currently I have already implemented the custom form way(which you have mentioned), but the concern here is first admin needs to create the column for the list (out of box) then he has to come to this custom form and do the necessary changes, again this is not user friendly and confusing for them,